# SQL HierarchyId GetAllDescendants of given parent LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to convert following SQL left join which gives me all descendants of given parent to LINQ query but couldn't get it right.
Table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE OrgStructure(
    [Id] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
    [NodeLevel]  AS ([Id].[GetLevel]()),
    [NodeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT p2.* FROM [dbo].[OrgStructure] p1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[OrgStructure] p2 
    ON p2.Id.IsDescendantOf(p1.Id) = 1
WHERE 
    p1.NodeId =@parent
```

LINQ Query which I tried:

```
 int parent = 3;
 var query = from p1 in dbContext.OrgStructure
             join p2 in dbContext.OrgStructure on p1.NodeId equals p2.NodeId
             where p1.Id.IsDescendantOf(p2.Id) == true && p2.NodeId == parent
             select p1;
```

Comment: If you're going to put the on part of the join in the where then you should just do a Cartesian join instead `from p1 in OrgStructure from p2 in OrgStructure`.